# HTTP Error 307 - Temporary redirect in Node.js (Express), passport.js , mongoose.js and Android app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, rest, express

I am building a REST Api using Node.js (Express.js and Moongose.js), I have one post route which takes the json and redirect it to signup (app/signup) if user is first time user (not available in database)  or to login (app/login) if the user is already a returning user (means user is available in the database).

here is the code  (I am using ECMAScript 2015 code using node 4.2.1 and use strict mode).

```
// Signup process happens here
  app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/signup'
  }));

  // Hit server to login
  app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
  }));
```

and the redirection happens form this code .

```
app.post(‘/loginorsignup', (req, res) => {
    let username      =  req.body.email; // actually email used for facebook login
    let password      =  req.body.id; // actually facebook tooken id

    User.findOne({'local.username': username}, (err, user) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.json({error: {message: err}});
      }
      if(user){
        return res.redirect(307,`/login?username=${username}&password=${password}`);
      } else {
        return res.redirect(307, `/signup?username=${username}&password=${password}`);
      }
    });
  });
```

the input json is

```
{
    “email” : “some@email.com”,
    “id”: “someid” 
}
```

This setup works perfectly while using postman (web api, chrome app) but while using android I got 
***HTTP Error 307 - Temporary redirect (How to fix it, it should be fixed in android app or node.js)***

Why it is done like this?

The android app use facebook login system and after the successful facebook login it sends data to the server  and server stores it and marked as loggedin and  that logged in user visit many routes which are authenticated using passport.js

Please help me to learn more about REST API. If you think that this is the bad way then please me provide some link which show how to handle the same scenario in REST API

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mostly redirection of URLs supposed to occur with low level urls only.

This error occurs on two cases:- 
1)  Web server is not giving alternative URL on 307 response
2)  The total number of redirections are exceeded by 5.

How To Fix It:-

First of all you have to check out the IP name so that we can figure out whether the account is accurate. In case your ISP has configured something then the access to the name should be redirected to the another name and it supposed to be permanent. You will require to update CheckUpDown account so that you can begin with using of new name.

You will need to update the new URL. In case it is a temporary redirection then you have to reinstate your original IP name to the later date so that redirection wont work any more.